# Encoding multiple layers of information with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, storage, mat

How would one best optimize the encoding of multiple layers of data points with OpenCV?

For example, if there is a picture of a forest, and I want to encode large labels like 'forest', medium size labels like 'tree', then small labels like 'leaf', or 'branch', one pixel might have 3 labels: forest, tree, leaf, and then for each of these, there could be a probability value.

This is a relatively simplistic example, but one could imagine having far more overlapping labels.

The easiest way would be to just have one cv::Mat for each possible label, but my question is more towards the best way to optimize memory usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use bits to encode this information. For example, suppose you are using 8U image (1 byte per pixel). Then you can use something like

```
0x01 : leaf
0x02 : tree
0x04 : forest
```

to represent these features. Here you are using a bit mask for each feature, so you can `OR` these values if a pixel belongs to more than one class.

So,

`0x03` would be `leaf, tree`

`0x06` would be `tree, forest`

For confidence levels you will have to use separate channels. If you are okay with losing some precision, you can use 8U channels for these instead of 32F channels. So, rather than storing 0.6578 in a float, you can store it as 66 in a byte.

If the matrix created this way contains lot of zeros, you can further reduce the memory usage by storing it as a sparse matrix.

Comment: That's a good idea, but how would I also save the "confidence" factor

Comment: @Victor.dMdB I didn't notice the confidence level. You'll have to add separate channels for those. At least you can save lot of space by encoding class label in bits.

Comment: @Victor.dMdB If you are okay with losing some precision, you can use 8U channels for storing confidence levels. For example, rather than storing a float 0.6578, you can store it as a 66 in a byte. Good luck!

Comment: Be careful never to save any *"bit encoded"* data in a lossy format such as JPEG. You can easily store, say 40, at a pixel location and save the file and read back 32...

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, indeed, if the OP wants to store this information in a persistent store. I wasn't thinking of that when i posted the answer.